# I am currently trying to deploy to pm2-meteor with an error

Tags: meteor, pm2, nvm

pm2-meteor node, npm, pm2 missing error...

Hello, I am currently trying to deploy to pm2-meteor with an error.

The current situation is that I want to modify product that was developed by previous developer as meteor using mac.

I use Windows.

Although not particularly relevant, the first error that occurred was the package-lock.json error of product, which was significantly changed when meteor npm install. So I just got node modules for npm install.

Then I tried to modify the code and deploy it using the pm2-meteor.

An error occurs.

```
Building your app and deployment to host machine \
Missing node
Missing npm
Missing pm2
```

Since previous developers used nvm, I also installed nvm and now my nvm folder is configured as shown in the figure.

`

```
> {   "appName": ",   
>"appLocation": {"local": "../"   },  
>"meteoSettingsLocation": ", 
>"meteoSettingsInRepo": false,   "prebuildScript": ",  
> MeteorBuildFlags: "--architecture os.linux.x86_64",   
> "Env": {
>     "ROOT_URL": ",
>     "PORT": "3000",
>     "MONGO_URL": ""   },   "server": {
>     "host": ",
>     "username": "root",
>     "deploymentDir": ",
>     "loadProfile": ",
>     "nvm": {
>       "bin": "~/.nvm/nvm.sh",
>       "use": "8.8.1"
>     },
>     "exec_mode": "cluster_mode",
>     "instances": "0",
>     "password": ""   },   "allowUndeployment": true }
```

`
Above is a .json file. I deleted personal information.

However, I use nvm-windows because nvm does not support Windows.

This is a list I've tried so far.

1. Reinstall the mateor
2. Delete existing node.js and reinstall nvm
3. Reinstall pm2 and pm2-meteor
4. Reconfigure the json file using the command in pm2-meteor (init)
5. Rewrite the nvm path of the json file(above json file) to the location of the nvm on my computer

a part of my doubt

1. The discrepancy between nvm used by the former developer in mac and nvm-windows used in windows

Currently, pm2-meteor and pm2 are properly stored in the v8.8x folder in the nvm folder.

Please give me a good direction.

Comment: Hi, are you able to deploy simpler meteor applications with no problem? If so, can you deploy the original (unmodified) meteor application? It feels to me that you have too many variables here, you need to get a baseline working before you try changing the code. I may be missing something though.

Comment: @MandyShaw thanks comment MandyShaw, But it's a project I've inherited, so there's a limit I can touch.

Comment: I think you might need to run a `meteor npm install` to get your modules in a row

Comment: Can't you create a new project to practise on, leaving the current one alone? It's just not fair to expect you to pick up a technology from scratch and amend a production application that was developed on a different platform, without having a chance to familiarise yourself properly.